# WordPress theme customization healing-touch theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have downloaded a theme from WordPress and I have created a child theme on this. Now I have style.css for this.

My requirement is to customize this as per my need. I am facing issues on this.
What is the best way to customize the theme.

For example, by default Archives and Category links are shown in my page.
I want to remove this. Also I want alter the layout of the page.
How to do this . My theme name is healing-touch.(https://wordpress.org/themes/healing-touch/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To change the layout of the page you need to find its template page file.
try searching in:
`your-website-name -> wp-content -> themes ->  your-theme-name`.

Search for the `html/php` file of the page you want to change, usually its called: `page-home.php / page.php`.

If you do not have ftp access to these files you can search for them in your wp-admin dashboard:
`appearance -> editor -> home-page.php`.

It looks like in this theme the Archives and Category are sidebar widgets. In order to remove them you can go to the left menu in your wp-admin dashboard:
`appearance -> Widgets`.
then just drag the unwanted widgets from the sidebar box.

If they do not appear there search in:
`yourwebsitename -> wp-content -> themes -> healing-touch -> sidebar.php`
(or in the dashboard: `appearance -> editor -> sidebar.php` )
and delete the parts you don't want to use.

Comment: Instead of editing the theme directly, they should create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Otherwise their changes will be lost when the theme is updated.